# Checking values on a pie chart, deleting if 0%

Tags: excel, vba

I have to print out a few thousand pie charts. I don't want to show 0% and was trying to make a macro that would check for that value and then delete if it was 0%. I used Record Macro to get the following:

```
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Select    
    Selection.Delete
```

So I tried to add an if statement like this:

```
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Select
    If Selection.Value = 0 Then
    Selection.Delete
    End If
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to check the value?

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Better give an error description or an [mcve] of the issue. Screenshots would help too to understand the issue better. Note that `.Points(1)` only checks the first point. So you will probably need a loop tho loop through all the points and check each point. and if there are more than one serries collections you need a second loop that loops through all of them too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because a DataLabel has no `Value` property. It has a `Caption`-property, so you could check if the caption is `0%`, but that's rather dirty and will fail if the data label is formatted differently (eg showing absolute values).

You can check the value itself by reading the `Values`-property of the data series that is displayed, that's much cleaner.

Furthermore, you should avoid using `Select`. The macro recorder needs to work on `Selection`, but as a programmer, you can use the matching objects directly.

---

I would suggest that you don't delete the labels. Problem with deleting is that once the data is changed and the value is no longer 0, it will be tricky to get it back. The following code is not deleting the labels but just makes them invisible by setting the height to 0. When the values changes and you run the code again, it will get it's original height and is visible again.

The following routine sets the labels for one chart:

```
Sub HideZeroValueLabels(ch As Chart)
    ' Get the Values of the data series
    Dim vals
    vals = ch.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values
    
    ' First loop: Remember height of labels (for restore)
    Dim i As Long, p As Point, maxPointLableHeight As Double
    For i = 1 To ch.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
        Set p = ch.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
        On Error Resume Next
        If p.DataLabel.Height > maxPointLableHeight Then maxPointLableHeight = p.DataLabel.Height
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    
    ' Second loop: Set height to 0 if value is 0, this makes it invisible
    For i = 1 To ch.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
        Set p = ch.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
        On Error Resume Next
        If vals(i) = 0 Then
            p.DataLabel.Height = 0
        Else
            p.DataLabel.Height = maxPointLableHeight
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

You can call the routine for every Pie chart of a sheet:

```
Sub ChangeAllPieCharts
    Dim co As ChartObject, ch As Chart
    For Each co In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Set ch = co.Chart
        If ch.ChartType = xl3DPie Or ch.ChartType = xl3DPieExploded _
        Or ch.ChartType = xlPie Or ch.ChartType = xlPieExploded Then
            HideZeroValueLabels ch
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Or for example only for the selected chart:

```
Sub ChangeSelectedPieCharts
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DPie Or ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DPieExploded _
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie Or ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPieExploded Then
        HideZeroValueLabels ActiveChart 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like a great approach and I do see the benefits of that.

However when I copy pasted the code into Excel it didn't work. It would not even show up on the list of Macros. If I changed `Sub HideZeroValueLabels(ch As Chart)` to `Sub HideZeroValueLabels()` it would show up but not work.

What do I need to change?

Comment: **FunThomas** mentioned that I should avoid using 'Select', I had the impression that is was a thing to get the macro recorder running. However I have no idea of how to point to the objects without using 'Select'. Where can I find a good guide to understand how the objects work and are pointed to?

For example I am still not sure how I point to a specific piechart and then pinpoint the DataLabels. I do not understand what the following lines actually do 
'Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set a = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

Valueschart = a.Values

Any guides to recommend?

Comment: The list of Macros in Excel (not in VBA) shows only Subs without parameter (because Excel cannot pass a parameter from the Macro menu). I edited my answer to show how you could call the Sub, one will change *all* pie charts of a Sheet, one will change only the selected chart. Both have no parameter and can be called from the Macro menu.

Comment: Thanks again @FunThomas
It works now, now I will just need to spend some time trying to figure out what is happening.

One question: How would I restore the height of the zero values?

Comment: Instead of setting the height to 0, set it to any value > 0, eg `maxPointLableHeight`, or a fixed number - try what fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you:

```
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set a = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

Valueschart = a.Values
    
For x = LBound(Valueschart) To UBound(Valueschart)
    If Valueschart(x) = 0 Then
        With a.Points(x)
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Delete
        End With
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: I think he only wants to delete the `DataLabels` and not the entire chart object `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Delete`.

Comment: Sorry for never coming back. The handling of the issue was handed over to someone else, so I didn't need to handle it. Now it has been handed back to me and still only solvable by deleting them one by one.

Yes, I only want to delete the DataLabels. How do I do that?